# how to call python function in html tag

Tags: html, python-3.x, django-templates

I have created a function to extract pdf text but i am unable to display the output on html page.
in html file -
file name = userInput.html

```
<form action="">
  <label for="usr">Select PDF File:</label>
  <input type="file" id="PDFupload">
  <input type="submit" id='file_submit'> 
</form>
<label>Extracted Data From Selected PDF File</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Text Data of PDF">
```

in python (file name pdf2txt.py)

```
#!c:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
   def pdf_on_html():
       import PyPDF2
       a = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('select file from html page where id="PDFupload"')
       print(a.getPage(0).extractText())
   pdf_on_html()
```

now i want to display the output text on html page where placeholder="Text Data of PDF"
i have tried to use

1. src="python.py" type="text/python" in script.
2. Brython.
3. django.
4. bs4.

i am looking for both code, html and python as well. but i am getting only one side code hence unable to link properly.